# Is there a minimum charge for query listener in firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I was going through the [pricing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing) page of firestore and there is a [mention](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#minimum-charge) of minimum charge for queries where even if the query returns no results, there is a minumum charge of one document read.

Now instead of issuing a query, I am attaching [query listenere](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#listens) using addSnapshotListener. IN my case, this listener may not return any documents. Now, on detaching the listener, is there a minimum charge of one document read even in this case?

In the page, there is no mention of this charge for query listeners. I am not sure if minimum charge of query also applies here to the query listeners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attaching a listener is a form of a read operation. So according to the documentation on [Firestore billing of read, write and delete operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations):

> You are charged for each document read, write, and delete that you perform with Cloud Firestore.

---

Another way to understand this: attaching a listener essentially starts with a normal get operation, which is a charged operation. For a read that returns no documents this means that your project is charged 1 document read when you attach/detach a listener in quick succession.